# Docker with Angular 2: cannot get

Tags: json, angular, docker

We're trying to set up an Angular 2 application with Docker following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-and-docker-compose

The application deploys but we get 'Cannot GET /'

This is how we build our app:

```
sudo docker build -t frontend:dev .
```

and this is how we run our app

```
sudo docker run -d --name frontend -p 1014:4200 frontend:dev
```

Our dockerfile is exactly the same as the tutorial:

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:6

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And this is an excerpt from package.json

```
{
  "name": "courseka",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0"
    "build": "ng build"
  }
}
```

And as last, something from our index.html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: The trace would help a lot. But `Cannot GET /` looks like a missed HTTP call. So eityher your don't have the right `<base href="/">`, or you didn't set your server correctly

Comment: Did you check the docker logs? Is your server running properly?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was a Linux-Windows issue. The development op the app happened on Windows where the import folders and classes are case-insensitive, while on Linux they are and two imports were wrongly capitalized.

The problem was detected by running with the

```
-it
```

parameter, that logs all the output

Comment: can you explain your answer?